# implementing distributed system which can store multimedia

Tags: server, multimedia, distributed-system

I want to create a distributed system on which i will store large video files. The system should be able to serve multiple client at a given point of time. Also the system should be scalable and always available(ie. if one machine is down, the data should be served from another machine on the system). How do i implement such system.

Comment: By starting designing, planning and implementing it. As a question this is way too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: How to implement type of questions are not meant for SO. Use Quora or something similar or any forum.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately I'll be voting to close your question as "too broad". There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Answer (score 1):

Try LizardFS lizardfs.com - few render farms are built on that.
There is no limit of the file size and it can handle thousands of clients.
It has also High Availability mechanism.